# "Filter" Queries from Azure App Service

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I have the following Azure SQL table consisting of:

```
id   customerid   value
01            1    test
02            1    none
03            2    exam
04            2    what
05            3    rule
06            4    game
```

I have multiple customers that are supposed to use this app (E.g. customer1,customer2 etc.)

At the moment I am able to sync ALL data in this table to my app but I would like to "filter" the data so that customer1 only is able to sync his/her rows from Azure SQL to the app.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking. You know how to filter (`Where(...)`, so what's the trouble you're facing?

Comment: Where works well when the data is synced to the app. What I mean is that some data (e.g. id 3,4,5,6) should never be synced to the app.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're talking about. If you refer to some walkthrough, don't expect everyone to have read it. A description like *how do I return a row containing some special text or value* is very vague.

Comment: Ok. I rewrote the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add additional Where() clauses to your query, so for example:

var items = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => !todoItem.Done && todoItem.customerid == *id of current user here*).ToEnumerableAsync();

Comment: This query works against the local data already synced to the app. I want to avoid customer == 1 to not be able to sync other data than row 1-2.

Comment: Perhaps I don't completely follow your previous example then. If that linq query is against the database it should only bring down that data, but yes if that is a query against the already downloaded data, the only option that I can think of currently is to look into [Row Level Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx)

Comment: Think you are on to something here good sir! Will check it out!